# mysqldump working on local but not on godaddy server

Tags: php, mysql, shell

I had used php exec shell commands to get the dump of database. Its working fine on local but when i run that same php file on server, it says
'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I am using the database credentials of the live database on godaddy server with windows hosting(PLESK)

```
shell_exec('mysqldump --host='.$mysqlHostWithNoPort.' --password='.$mysqlPassword.' '.$DbName.' --user='.$mysqlUserName.' --single-transaction>DB_Backup/'.$filename .' 2>&1');
```

I had defined the variables used above in my config file.

Comment: Have you asked the host if the have it

Comment: I run that mysql dump command on local cmd, it works..@Dagon

Comment: @KuHyeSun as you said `local`. It is a big difference between `local` and `host`. You may not even have permission to use `shell_exec` command. If you want to use the shell commands, you may want to look into dedicated host.

Comment: file is creating, it means shell is working but mysqldump not working.. What do i need to ask from the host? I googled and find that before writing mysqldump, i have to give the path where mysqldump is present. Can we get that where mysqldump is present? @Dagon

Comment: Ask godaddy to walk you thru it. That is what you pay them for.